# Form gives validation error every time unless page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a php/html/form that is giving me problems. What happens is the form gives me validation error upon submitting unless I refresh the page and get it correct the first time. If I input incorrect validation then I must refresh the page again or else it will give me error over and over. And it must be correct the very first time after page load, or else it will just keep giving error until you refresh and get it right the.very first time.

After that I am would like to pass the user submitted data to the next page using PHP.

```
<form action='load' method='GET' onsubmit="return Validate();">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter btc address" name="btcaddress" pattern="^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Correct address format required.')" required>
    </div>
    <center>
        <button type="submit"><b>Go</b></button>
    </center>
</form>
```

Could this be happening because I am testing on my Linux machine with Atom and the PHP Server plugin? Address http://localhost:8000

Comment: We can't see your localhost. You need to show the php code

Comment: Is the validation error server side? There's a `Validate()` call on the form, show javascript too just in case.

Comment: What? I don't hvae any PHP code yet. The form validation comes from the bitcoin address regex validation as mentioned in question details I am validfating a bitcoin address. This is what does the validating: `pattern="^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$"` and there is no javascript for this form, not that I know of. Can someone help me to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: You have to clear `customValidity`, it's not automatic. And again, there's a `Validate()` function call in your `form` tag.

Comment: How do I clear it?

Comment: did you get to fix this error ? how ?